# JSON Object cannot be converted to JSONArray Search App

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i´d like to create a search for my Android app but when I try to I just get the JSON Value along with ...JSON Object cannot be converted to JSONArray. Btw I am using Volley.

Code Sample for getting JSON:

```
   private void getData() {

    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.i_enter_request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,getString(R.string.d_wait),getString(R.string.d_fetch),false,false);

    String url = AppConfig.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

    JsonArrayRequest searchReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.dismiss();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject pObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            Products item = new Products();

                            item.setTitle(pObj.getString("name"));

                            ProductItems.add(item);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loading.dismiss();

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(searchReq);
}
```

And the JSON itself by searching for "1":

```
{
    products: [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Test",
        price: "123",
        item_desc: "Its a Test"
    }],
    success: 1
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me with it.
Thanks

Comment: your response is not a jsonarray. but your error already tells you that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSONArray:

`{products:[{id: "1", name: "Test", price: "123", item_desc: "Its a Test" } ], success: 1 }`

So you're getting an error because your callback tries passing it in as a `JSONArray` You need to change your callback to:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {}
```

And then you need to parse the response as a JSONObject, not a JSONArray.

Comment: The correct answer should be to use Volley's `JsonObjectRequest`. OP can't just change `JSONArray` to `JSONObject` in the callback

Comment: @cricket_007 - Soooo...why not post that as an answer instead of criticizing my answer? :) I don't really know anything about volley, so I was just offering what I knew was causing the error. If you have a better answer, please post it, as I would love to learn more and I'm sure OP would appreciate it!

Comment: Your "combined" answer helped me fixing the problem. Thank you both ;-)

Comment: You were technically right, but the method you pointed out belonged to a different class